# UITableViewCell height is not fitted when hiding UIView inside the cell using AutoLayout

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, autolayout

I have been struggling this issue for 3 days and still can not figure it out. I do hope anyone here can help me.

Currently, i have an UITableView with customized cell(subclass of UITableViewCell) on it. Within this customized cell, there are many UILabels and all of them are set with Auto Layout (pining to cell content view) properly. By doing so, the cell height could display proper height no matter the UILabel is with long or short text.

[image]

The problem is that when i try to set one of the UILabels (the bottom one) to be hidden, the content view is not adjusted height accordingly and so as cell.

What i have down is i add an **Hight Constraint** from Interface Builder to that bottom label with following.

```
Priority = 250 (Low)
Constant = 0
Multiplier = 1
```

This make the constrain with the dotted line. Then, in the Swift file, i put following codes.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
   super.viewDidLoad()
  //Setup TableView
  tableView.allowsMultipleSelectionDuringEditing = true

  //For tableView cell resize with autolayout
  tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
  tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 200

}
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, willSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> NSIndexPath? {
 let cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! RecordTableViewCell
 cell.lbLine.hidden = !cell.lbLine.hidden
 if cell.lbLine.hidden != true{
  //show
  cell.ConstrainHeightForLine.priority = 250
 }else{
  //not show
  cell.ConstrainHeightForLine.priority = 999
}

//tableView.reloadRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.None)
return indexPath
```

}

The tricky thing is that when i call **tableView.reloadRowAtIndexPaths()**, the cell would display the correct height but with a bug that it has to be trigger by double click (selecting) on the same row rather than one click.

For this, i also try following code inside the **willSelectRowAtIndexPath** method, but none of them is worked.

```
cell.contentView.setNeedsDisplay()
cell.contentView.layoutIfNeeded()
cell.contentView.setNeedsUpdateConstraints()
```

Currently the result is as following (with wrong cell Height):
[image]

As showed in the Figure 2, UILabel 6 could be with long text and when i hide this view, the content view is still showing as large as it before hiding.
Please do point me out where i am wrong and i will be appreciated.

Comment: Can you show the IB screenshot depicting constraints? that might give better picture.

Comment: try moving that    tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
 to cell for row at index path and do reload  tableView in side willSelect method. if it is not working then try to add main view to cell that covers whole cell and then add those labels that you needed. pin that main view to 4 sides of cell for resizing the cell. hope it will help !

Comment: @Shripada , due to the reputation, i could only put 2 photos by imgur, please have a look. thxs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally change the code

```
tableView.reloadRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.None)
```

to the following

```
tableView.reloadData()
```

Then, it work perfectly.
However, i don't really know the exactly reason on it. Hope someone can still comment it out.